# Facebook like button: How do I prevent people accidently "unliking" my page?

Tags: php, facebook, button, facebook-like

I want to prevent users the ability to unlike my page having clicked they like it because I have it prominently displayed next to my site's header.  I am afraid that people will accidentally "unlike" my page having already clicked it once to like it.

So far I have explored a php proxy so I can use a custom css page.  Anyone else have any ideas?  What about a non-iframe facebook like button?

Comment: You should consider that they might accidentaly 'like' your page as well.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to keep people from "unliking" your page. If that's not what you want to know, you should clarify your question. If you do want to prevent users from "unliking" your page, you should consider creating something worth "liking".

Comment: How do you tell the difference between *accidental* unliking and *purposeful* unliking? Measuring the user's brain waves?

Comment: By the way, if they accidentaly unlike it they'll certainly click like again.
I'd recommend you collect some statistics... track the clicks. If there's more than a click on 'like/unlike' per session, they're clicking accidentally. If not then there's no problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, preventing from double click might be hard, 
but after your page loaded you can get the text the inside of fb like box element, learn the id via firebug) if it is 'liked', you can hide the box..

of course you can do this only for fbml, not for iframe. 
otherwise, you can't!

i suggest you to check other likebox styles. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box